Azure open AI while developing python script using api key getting error
import openai

# Setup
openai.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
openai.api_base = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

openai.api_version = '2024-08-20'  # Ensure this is correct

def test_openai():
    try:
        response = openai.Image.create(
            prompt="A dog in rain image",
            model="dall-e-3",  # Try with a different model ifneeded
            n=1,
            size="1024x1024"
        )
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

test_openai()


Error: Resource not found
I have created azure open ai model dall-e-3
the api key and api base both worked with model gpt-35-turbo

Please print the full error, If it is openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Resource not found, it means the API endpoint you're requesting does not exist or not available. Double check your api_base and api_version (most api_version ends with -preview)

Adding to previous comment, model is the name you give, not the default Azure model name.

I am getting below error and i am using openai =0.28 and deployement name  = dall-e-3   , openai.api_version = '2024-08-20'
I believe i made  api_version error where to check in the documention I searched but unable to find out
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Resource not found

The error you are getting because you need to use the Deployment name instead of the Model name.

You need to create client to connect  to generate result.
Below code worked for me.
I am using a Flask app to use the openai code and view the generated image in index.html file.
app.py:
from flask import Flask,render_template
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_image_url():

    try:
        client = AzureOpenAI(
        api_version="2024-05-01-preview",
        azure_endpoint="https://xxxxxxxxxx.openai.azure.com/",
        api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        )

        result = client.images.generate(
            model="dallechatgpt",
            prompt="A dog in rain image",
            n=1
        )

        image_url = json.loads(result.model_dump_json())['data'][0]['url']

        return render_template('index.html',image_url=image_url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error{e}")
        

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run()

templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if image %}
    <h2>Generated Image:</h2>
    <img src="{{ image }}" alt="Generated Image" style="width: auto; height: 50vh;">
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>

requirements.txt:
flask
openai

OUTPUT:


changed azure_endpoint, api_key I got below error
C:/Users/Comp/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "d:/API CODE /image1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\API CODE \image1.py", line 3, in 
from openai import AzureOpenAI
ImportError: cannot import name 'AzureOpenAI' from 'openai' (C:\Users\Comp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openai_init_.py)
tried this also but still pip install azure-ai-openai,  azure-cognitiveservices-openai

@BandaruPrudhvi add openai in requirements.txt, added my requirements.txt file data

or use pip install openai

It worked thank you

@BandaruPrudhvi  Glad it helped
